# Geometry Nodes: How to iterate a Vertex Color gradient across geometries?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, vertex-colors, data-blocks

I want the geometry I create in Geometry Nodes to be generated with a Vertex Color gradient that I can use in the object's material.

In this example there are several rectangles, one original, and three more generated at each iteration of the Node Group.

[image: Geometry Nodes iterative stepped gradient across geometry parts]

Here's the inside of the Node Group:

[image: grouped Geometry Nodes]

As you can see, it's not really doing anything special in its current state. Just recursively creating a new transformed rectangle in each iteration. Brightness is supposed to get added in each iteration too, to step from black (`0.0`) to white (`1.0`), but this is not working.

In order to match the example I manually painted, the grayscale values should instead be approximately `0.0`, `0.33`, `0.66`, `1.0`.

The other (possibly greater) problem, is that despite being a property of vertices, vertex color appears not to be uniquely linked to each separate island of geometry.

If anyone knows how to do this, please share. I would like to access gradients from mesh vertices within my material, instead of having to make a separate material for each island of geometry. Thanks!

[**Example .blend file**](https://pasteall.org/blend/29f723f8fae4485f8b74aa772a635744) <sub>(Made with Blender 3.0.1)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

There are a few small problems in your node tree:

- your inputs and outputs are pink (= boolean) but you want to store Fac, which is a float. Boolean are either 1 or 0. No other value.

-> also inputs and outputs of your group node have to be changed

i hope/think, what you want is that?

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The result is looking good! Is there also a way to do this using the **Join Geometry** node? Or is it only possible using **Instance on Points**? Because although I kept my example simple, what I ultimately want to do will involve more complex geometries, and I was planning to join them.

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure whether i understand you right. Of course you could do a "join geometry" at the end of my tree - it would work. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: i have no idea now, how it should work because then you would have only one mesh which you cannot "separate" as you can do it with instances. I am sorry. Maybe some other GN pro's know how to do that.

Comment: I've been playing with different node setups. I feel like I'm close. Could you please take a look at [my .blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/7d4bef6cad16412cb7b0818160dfa27c)? Join is working, but the gradient is spread across the vertices, without treating each iteration of geometry as having its own "step" value. Maybe the ID Node could be the key?

Comment: will your x values always be stable? so you could easily use the x values ;)

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not that simple. I'd like the group to be able to handle meshes of any shape, location, rotation, etc.

Comment: but then you node tree wouldn't work at all with different meshes because now you depend on index which if dependent on how " big" your mesh is....

Comment: Yeah, having to rely on index is the limitation. A "Set Vertex Weight" node would fix this. Too bad there is no such node (yet). Ideally we could specify the name of the vert group to edit (or create new from selection), and have an input slider for the weight value. It would also be useful if there were a way to handle the scaling of all weights of a group together. These kinds of operations are really easy when manually managing objects in the viewport, so naturally users will want to do them in GN too. A wishful observation in case devs are reading... ;-)

Comment: maan I just wanna thank you from the bottom of my heart cuz I am doing a light strip with all the individual led controlled by a color ramp and I couldn't find a way to translate the color ramp color to the leds (I just started guessing it prob had smt to do with the index) and after searching for days - I found your answer now and it's the exact solution. Thank you!!! :'D