# Can‘t use Weight Painting to control the density

Tags: weight-painting, geometry-nodes

I want to put some sesame on bun,some places have much sesame, some places have few, so I goes to weight paint and want to use weight to control the density factor in GN.
But no matter what weight it is ,it shows the same density, and when I want to delete some sesame,it still stay there. So what can I do?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geometry Nodes: How to iterate a Vertex Color gradient across geometries?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255215/geometry-nodes-how-to-iterate-a-vertex-color-gradient-across-geometries)

Comment: not the same question, but same answer

Comment: It's not the same problem.There must be a place that store the weight paint number which is 0~1,that's works to the factor, but in my way, it don't work.Maybe I don't get the number, I don't know how.

Comment: Yes, you can fix your problem by using a float input instead of boolean (pink) input

Comment: Thanks,I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is your density. Weight paint is just between 0 and 1 and that's why you don't see your difference. So you have to multiply that value.

Comment: I use poisson Disk and what I link is the density factor not density, so it should be 0~1, but I finally found out why.Because at a very first try, I link the input to selection, although I change it immediately and never use the link again, the input style keeps the same: "selection", that means no matter what weight is , the input is a boolean. Thanks for your case, it gives me a comparison to help me find out the mistake.

Comment: Indeed, in the group input node the type must be changed from boolean to color - this was the solution for me as well. Perhaps it would be helpful for others to mention this in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

So you want the sesame to be spread on top of the bun randomly. And then add in your weight paint?

I did it the following way: Group input here I have one more going to a Math Multiply node going into Density Max of the Distribute Points on Faces node. I also have a Rotate Euler in it for the rotation. Best way to do it the way you want is to watch Blender Guru Donut 3.0 part 9 he explains it well

Comment: I want to use something to control the density wherever I want.

Comment: Ahh thats why it looked so weird to answer thanks

Comment: I have watch his video，but I think he has the same problem and just neglect that.He just  paint where the sugar is, but can't control the density by weight paint number, I mean different place has different density.